# setting/properties type setup

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I would like to have the possibility of specifying certain "properties" either during setup of my app or afterwards.

In my app I have a connection to my mysql server,currently localhost, but when I am going to install this the localhost will probably change to an IP address or hostname, is there any way that I can create like a properties box that asks the user what he/she wants the ip address or hostname to be to connect to,and then once they change it it should reflect in the code? Or maybe have an encrypted text file with all the settings in or a text file thats hidden with the settings in,not sure what the right approach will be, thank you for your answers and advise

Answer (score 0):

You can store sensitive data in connection strings by encrypting them, see [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).